# ContinueDestinationPageUrl Property

Tags: vb.net, createuserwizard

I am trying to use the Continue Destination PageURL property and not sure if i am doing this right or wrong.

What i want ? I want to redirect the page back to create new user, once a user is created. I am using the CreateUserWizard and this is the code i have.

```
  <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server"  BackColor="Green" 
    BorderColor="#B5C7DE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" Height="278px" Width="278px" ContinueDestinationPageUrl = "~/jinx/Usr.aspx">
    <SideBarStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Size="0.9em" VerticalAlign="Top" />
```

Not sure if that is the right way of defining a continueDestinationPageURL. If i just go with this, and create a new user, it takes me back to the login screen, instead of keeping me logged in and back to the create new user screen.

Any help is appreciated,
-W

Comment: From the information provided, it looks right. Are you sure your code is not somehow logging you out? This should make the security in your web.config send you back to the login screen if done right.  That my best guess.

Comment: I am just not sure, this is indeed making me logout. Rather i don't want to logout. Is there any other property which ia missing ?

Comment: I dont use the wizards so I cannot tell you if *it* is but you should look at your CODE to see if you are accidently logging yourself out after creating a new user.

Comment: Found the solution, the key was the LoginCreatedUser ="false" property needs to be set along with the ContinueDestinationPageUrl Property.

Comment: Makes sense. After creating the user, the wizard assumed you then wanted to login as that user. Good catch.